# Calling Function from `do` Block

Tags: coffeescript

Why is the following code showing an error for `unique`?

```
do (unique = (-> ->), x = unique()) ->
  do (y = x) ->
    console.log "x is y:", x is y
```

**output**

```
ReferenceError: unique is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified your code to this (because it is what engenders the error)

```
do (unique = (-> ->), x = unique()) ->
    console.log "x is y:", x is y
```

The compiled version is:

```
(function(unique, x) {
  return console.log("x is y:", x === y);
})((function() {
  return function() {};
}), unique());
```

Which can also be written like this:

```
a=function(unique,x) {
      return console.log("x is y:", x === y);
    }
b=(function() {
      return function() {};
    })
a(b,unique)
```

As you can see, the last unique is not defined anywhere in the scope.

That's why you get this error.

I suggest you to **extract** `unique`:

```
unique = (-> ->)
do (unique, x = unique()) ->
  do (y = x) ->
    console.log "x is y:", x is y
```